# jQuery target in var reports r.fn.init(1) - Im trying to compare is same target got clicked twice

Tags: jquery

I have this code and Im trying to determine if same target got clicked twice. I dont want to use id of classes. 
If should work. Clicked object is stored in var selected and then compared again. What Im getting is r.fn.init(1) ???

ps> found this code on codepen (forgot who) but who ever made it did an excellent job on which I wish to expand...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var selected;
        var same = false;
            var headers = ["H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6","IMG"];

            $(".accordion").click(function(e) {
            var target = e.target, name = target.nodeName.toUpperCase();

            if ($(target) == $(selected)){ same = true } else { same = false }
            selected = $(target);

            if($.inArray(name,headers) > -1) {
                var subItem = $(target).next();

                //slideUp all elements (except target) at current depth or greater
                var depth = $(subItem).parents().length;
                var allAtDepth = $(".accordion p, .accordion .collapsable").filter(function() {
                if($(this).parents().length >= depth && this !== subItem.get(0)) {
                    return true; 
                }
                });

                $(allAtDepth).slideUp("fast");

                //slideToggle target content and position top of element at top of page
                subItem.slideToggle("fast", 
                    function(){
                            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-50 }, 200)
                    }
                    )
                }
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved... accessed var as array like
$(target)[0] == $(selected)[0]

Works